# Within Table Subquery of Identical Combinations

Tags: subquery, postgresql-9.0

I would like to select groups that have the exact same attributes from a table. For example, my table is like the following

```
facs_run_id |  fcj_id
    1       |     17
    1       |     4
    1       |     12
    2       |     17
    2       |     4
    2       |     12
    3       |     17
    3       |     12
    3       |     10
```

In this table each `facs_run_id` has different combinations of `fcj_id`, some are shared between `facs_run_id` numbers while others are not. For example, above `facs_run_id` `1` and `2` are identical, while `3` has shared `fcj_id` but is not identical to `1` and `2`. I would like to make query to:

1. gather all `fcj_id` from a particular `facs_run_id`
2. find all `facs_run_id` that have the exact same `fcj_id` combination.

Herein, I want to find all `facs_run_id` that are equal in `fcj_id` combinations to `facs_run_id: 1`, so it should return `2` (or `1` & `2`).

I can get those that are missing certain `fcj_id` and even find which `fcj_id` are missing with this:

```
SELECT facs_run_id 
FROM   facs_panel 
EXCEPT 
SELECT fcj_id 
FROM   facs_panel 
WHERE  facs_run_id = 2;
```

or this:

```
SELECT row(fp.*, fcj.fcj_antigen, fcj.fcj_color) 
FROM   facs_panel fp 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN facs_conjugate_lookup fcj ON fcj.fcj_id = fp.fcj_id
WHERE  fp.fcj_id  in ( SELECT fp.fcj_id 
                       FROM   facs_panel fp 
                       WHERE  fp.facs_run_id = 1);
```

But I am not able to make a query that returns IDENTICAL `facs_run_id`. I suppose this could be considered a way of looking for aggregated duplicates, but I don't know how to do that. Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated (or a better way to create the table if this type of query will not work).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with a couple CTEs:

```
with f1 as (select
                facs_run_id,
                array_agg(fcj_id) as flist
              from facs_panel
              group by facs_run_id),
     f2 as (select flist, count(*)
              from f1
              group by flist
              having count(*) > 1)
select f2.flist, f1. facs_run_id
  from f2
  join f1 on (f2.flist = f1.flist)
  order by flist, facs_run_id;
```

The data from the question, run through this query, produces:

```
   flist   | facs_run_id 
-----------+-------------
 {4,12,17} |           1
 {4,12,17} |           2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just found your answer now, but I am ready to redo all of this. Thank you.